# Remove Additional Parameter from post logout URL

Tags: identity, wso2, wso2-identity-server

When the user clicked on the logout button after successful logout user redirects back to `callbackurl` with additional query parameters.
You can see below the URL return

`https://localhost:9443/?sp={spname}&tenantDomain=carbon.super`

Can anyone please help me with how we can remove these two ***sp*** and ***tenantDomain*** parameters?

I found the below article, also there are these two additional parameters.

https://piraveenaparalogarajah.medium.com/rp-initiated-logout-with-wso2-identity-server-b1fde28c4d80

Can search the below text in the article for reference.

> 5. Redirect to post_logout_redirect_uri

Comment: Can you please check in your service source code these values are assigned as params?

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa you mean in service provider callbackurl?

Comment: yes, service `callback` url and other configurations you applied

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa yes url same as https://localhost:9443.i think this is default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be introduced with the fix done for https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/3266. It has added the service provider name and tenant domain as query parameters for the success flow as well in addition to the failure flows.

Unfortunately, there is no way to configure this. But you may report this at https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues and the team will decide whether this needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is reported for IS 5.10.0:https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/12723